# Excel workbook to Save As .pdf

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am working on a folder that includes 20+ Excel files and want to open each one of them, make some page setup changes, and finally save as .pdf . I am pretty much covered all the topics except saving as a .pdf .

I need to save the file as the same name as the Excel workbook. in the same folder.

Following code does the job except I need to give the name and select the folder to save it:

```
fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, fName, xlQualityStandard, , , , , True
```

Source : http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/651621-save-pdf-macro.html#post3232801

Can some one help me to optimize this to achieve my target?

Comment: First try use Object for the workbook instead of the ActiveWorkbook. Then  store the Fullname of the workbook and change the extension. e.g. `Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(...)`, `fName = oWB.FullName`, `fName = Replace(fName,".xlsx",".pdf")` You don't need GetSaveAsFilename for automation.

Comment: Not clear what I need to do here.

     Set owb = Workbooks.Open(....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I don't have a printer setup so can't test it)

```
fName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

If InStr(fName, ".") > 0 Then fName = Left(fName, InStrRev(fName, ".") - 1)

ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, fName & ".pdf", _
                                   xlQualityStandard, , , , , True
```

Comment: Let's hope @Isu_Wick doesn't have excel files with `.` before the file extension.